# DataStax DSE Cassandra SSL - Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Tags: ssl, cassandra, datastax, plaintext

I have been trying to enable client-to-node ssl communication in a single node cluster running Datastax (DSE) version 4.6 with Cassandra 2.0.11

After following the steps in the datastax documentation [documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/sec/secClientNodeEncryp.html)

I keep on getting the following error message;

INFO [Thread-3] 2015-01-25 09:00:21,383 ThriftServer.java (line 135) Listening for thrift clients...
ERROR [Thrift:1] 2015-01-25 09:00:30,486 TNegotiatingServerTransport.java (line 523) Failed to open server transport.
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:129)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TPreviewableTransport.readUntilEof(TPreviewableTransport.java:79)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TPreviewableTransport.preview(TPreviewableTransport.java:55)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport.open(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:186)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:516)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:405)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:196)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:671)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:504)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:127)
    ... 9 more
ERROR [Thrift:1] 2015-01-25 09:00:30,513 CustomTThreadPoolServer.java (line 222) Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to open server transport: unknown
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:524)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:405)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:196)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Here is my cassandra.yaml file

> client_encryption_options:
>
> enabled: true
>
> keystore: /home/ubuntu/.keystore
>
> keystore_password: ****
>
> truststore: /home/ubuntu/.truststore
>
> truststore_password: ****
>
> protocol: ssl
>
> store_type: JKS
>
> cipher_suites:
>
> [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]

Steps followed to create the keystore and truststore

> keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias node0 -keystore .keystore (used the hostname for first name & last name)
>
> keytool -export -alias node0 -file node0.cer -keystore .keystore
>
> keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias node0 -file node0.cer -keystore .truststore

I already fix the    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA bug they have in their documentation by downloading the required jar files from the oracle website http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

Answer (score 2):

This message shows that a client is trying to open an unencrypted connection.

First thought is check if client certificate auth is enabled. Read this: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/sec/secRunCqlsh.html

Here is a walkthrough for enabling cqlsh ssl connection: https://github.com/PatrickCallaghan/datastax-ssl-example